# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException when calling .query

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am facing this problem only on the live version, when testing on the emulator everything works fine.
here is my code

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String SQL_CREATE_NUTRI_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME_USER_DATA + "(" +
            _ID_USER_DATA + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COLUMN_USER_NAME + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_USER_GENDER + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_USER_HEIGHT + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_USER_WEIGHT + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_USER_WEIGHT_DATE + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_USER_MUSCLE_MASS + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_USER_MUSCLE_MASS_DATE + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_USER_FAT_MASS + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_USER_FAT_MASS_DATE + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_USER_ACTIVITY + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_USER_GOAL + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_USER_PHONE + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_USER_AGE_MILLIS + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_USER_EMAIL + " TEXT, " +
            TOKEN + " TEXT, " +
            TOKEN_TIME + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD + " TEXT);";

    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_NUTRI_TABLE);

}
```

the error is in the db.execSQL line

i have reviewed my columns that i need and they are all there, because i saw in other answers that some people forgot to add all of them

EDIT
the answer below helped, i had a problem in the declaration

Comment: Add Exact exception trace that you are facing.

Comment: @AshishKarn is this what you meant?

Comment: Please try this `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS + TABLE_NAME_USER_DATA + "("` let me know it is correct or not. It seems everything okay. Can you please provide `userDataProvider.query` method code or query.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] - this code can't be used without all the missing constants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change your query to not create a table if it already exists.

Like

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS + TABLE_NAME_USER_DATA + "(" +
```

And check.